# Editing a specific part of specific line of *.dat file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The line 5163 is **10,0.3**. This code written below edits the whole line to **5,0.3**. I want to just replace number **10** to **5** without replacing the whole line. I want to edit that specific part. How can this be done?

```
import os
import time

with open('Job-1.dat', 'rt') as fin:
    with open('out.dat', 'wt') as fout:
        for i, line in enumerate(fin):
            if i == 5163:
                fout.write(' 5, 0.3\n')
            else:
                fout.write(line)

os.remove('Job-1.dat')
time.sleep(5)
os.rename('out.inp', 'Job-1.inp')
```

Comment: The code does exactly what you want ... ?

Comment: I want to do something different. I just want to edit a part. This code edits the whole line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
        if i == 5163:
            fout.write(' 5, 0.3\n')
```

to:

```
        if i == 5163:
            items = line.split(',')
            out = ','.join(['10'] + items[1:])
            fout.write(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the last part of the line by replacing only what you want to replace:

```
# your code
        for i, line in enumerate(fin):
            if i == 5163:
                modified = line.replace("10,", "5,")
                fout.write(modified + '\n')
            else:
                fout.write(line)

# etc
```

See [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

As @Blotosmetek mentioned, adding a `'\n'` to each line (wich already contains one at the end) will lead to empty lines in your output file - in case thats not wanted, use

```
    fout.write(modified) # no extra '\n' added
```

Comment: Isn't adding an extra `\n` unnecessary?